# Manga volume for end of season 1 of Bleach anime

Tags: bleach

I am trying to find the manga volume where the 1st season of the Bleach anime left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia and from what I can surmise from the summaries there, [the entirety of Season 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach_(season_1)) is covered in [the first eight volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bleach_chapters_(1%E2%80%93187)), ending at about chapter 70, just a bit before they arrive to Soul Society.

If you want to pick it up from there, Volume 9 would be where you'd want to start from.

Comment: @Reecechips:  You're welcome, but [you should give this a read, too.](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)